# How to add custom attribute on Checkout. Billing.phtml file

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have created a custom module to create custom attribute for customer address.

It is a dropdown list attribute, this attribute shows on Admin customer address section. But  I want this attribute should also shows on checkout page while registering.

How Can I write a html for that attribute on billing.phtml file and save its data on database also.

[I have followed this website to create Module and Attribute](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/)

this is my attribute

attribute name - cstpb
Type - select
Frontend label -  Primary Business
Source - pb/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions14623605840

Please let me know how can add select attribute on billing.phtml and update its entry in config.xml

**Updates** -

Below is my code -

**File Name -**  `/app/code/local/PS/PB/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PS_PB>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </PS_PB>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <pb>
        <class>PS_PB_Helper</class>
      </pb>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <pb>
        <class>PS_PB_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>pb_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </pb>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <customerattribute1462360584_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>PS_P</module>
          <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
        </setup>
        <connection>
          <use>core_setup</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1462360584_setup>
      <customerattribute1462360584_write>
        <connection>
          <use>core_write</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1462360584_write>
      <customerattribute1462360584_read>
        <connection>
          <use>core_read</use>
        </connection>
      </customerattribute1462360584_read>
    </resources>
  </global>
</config>
```

**File -** `/app/code/local/PS/PB/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php
class PS_PB_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**File -**  `/app/code/local/PS/PB/Model/Eav/Entity/Attribute/Source/Customeroptions14623605840.php`

```
<?php
class PS_PB_Model_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Source_Customeroptions14623605840 extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("End Consumer / DIY"),
                    "value" =>  1
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Service Technician"),
                    "value" =>  2
                ),

                array(
                    "label" => Mage::helper("eav")->__("Other Professional"),
                    "value" =>  3
                ),

            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option["value"]] = $option["label"];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option["value"] == $value) {
                return $option["label"];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Column(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColums()
    {
        $columns = array();
        $columns[$this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode()] = array(
            "type"      => "tinyint(1)",
            "unsigned"  => false,
            "is_null"   => true,
            "default"   => null,
            "extra"     => null
        );

        return $columns;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Indexes(s) for Flat
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatIndexes()
    {
        $indexes = array();

        $index = "IDX_" . strtoupper($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode());
        $indexes[$index] = array(
            "type"      => "index",
            "fields"    => array($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode())
        );

        return $indexes;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Select For Flat Attribute update
     *
     * @param int $store
     * @return Varien_Db_Select|null
     */
    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel("eav/entity_attribute")
            ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
    }
}
```

**File -** `/app/code/local/PS/PB/sql/customerattribute1462360584_setup`

```
    <?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();


    $installer->addAttribute("customer_address", "cstpb",  array(
        "type"     => "int",
        "backend"  => "",
        "label"    => "Primary Business",
        "input"    => "select",
        "source"   => "pb/eav_entity_attribute_source_customeroptions14623605840",
        "visible"  => true,
        "required" => true,
        "default" => "",
        "frontend" => "",
        "unique"     => false,
        "note"       => ""

        ));

            $attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer_address", "cstpb");


    $used_in_forms=array();
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
    $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
    $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer_address";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_register_address";
    $used_in_forms[]="customer_address_edit";
            $attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_system", 0)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->setData("is_visible", 1)
            ->setData("sort_order", 100)
            ;
            $attribute->save();



    $installer->endSetup();
```

**XML File -** `/app/etc/modules/PS_PB.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <PS_PB>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </PS_PB>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Maybe you want to show what you have done so far?

Comment: @AlexanderBüse Please check updated question